# How to mark pinia action private

Tags: pinia

I have a pinia store action ("the Master Action") that mutates the store's state. This action is somewhat complicated, so i've broken it down into smaller "Child Actions" each of which mutates a small part of the store's state.

Question: How do I mark these Child Actions as private so that when the store is used in a component only the Master Action is available to be called?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Full answer [here](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/983#discussioncomment-2063235).

TL;DR - You can write your "Child Actions" outside of the `defineStore` (in the same file or in a different file), and pass `this` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best and not the Pinia internal solution, but I do put an underscore (`_`) in the action names to indicate that they are private. I can't prevent store users from using it, but it worked for me in my scenario.